# How to keep fixed height of mdframed in latex?

Tags: mdframed

I am designing one page in which i need to write 3 mdframed side by side. but all three must be having same height.

```
  <mdframed1>   <mdframed2>  <mdframed3>
```

How can i implement this?

Answer (score 3):

You can place each `mdframed` inside a `minipage` of the desired width (in this way, you can place sevearl `mdframes` side-by-side); inside each `mdframed` you can use a `\parbox` (or another `minipage`) of the predefined height. In the example below I implement this idea using a command with a mandatory argument (for the contents of the `mdframed`) and an optional argument to pass options to `mdframed`, but of course, you can implement the idea in any other way that suits your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcommand\FixedHt[2][]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.30\textwidth}
  \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=5pt,#1]
  \parbox[t][8cm][t]{\linewidth}{#2}
  \end{mdframed}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\FixedHt[backgroundcolor=cyan!20]{Some text}\hfill\FixedHt[backgroundcolor=orange!20]{Some text}\hfill\FixedHt[backgroundcolor=green!20]{Some text}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Easy job with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{%
  nobeforeafter,
  colframe=gray,
  boxrule=0.5pt,
  minipage,
  width=0.3\linewidth,
  height=8cm,               %%% <--- change here
  arc=3pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  #1
  }

\begin{document}

\noindent
\mybox[colback=cyan!20]{Some text}
\hfill
\mybox[colback=orange!20]{Some text}
\hfill
\mybox[colback=green!20]{Some text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to fit the contents within the box of specified height, look for `fitbox` option in `tcolorbox` (page 59, section 3.13)